# Angular 8: NG8002: Can't bind to 'ontime' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular

I'm receiving an error message for the below code:

```
<div *ngFor="let number of [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]; let ndx = index;" data-ontime="{{number}}" data-id="pane-{{number}}" (click)="myf('pane-1')">
 // codes
</div>
```

> error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ontime' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to create a custom attribute for an element, then you need to include `attr` keyword in front of custom attribute.

Change,

```
data-ontime="{{number}}"
```

to

```
attr.data-ontime="{{number}}"
```

So the complete code would be,

```
<div *ngFor="let number of [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]; let ndx = index;" attr.data-ontime="{{number}}" data-id="pane-{{number}}" (click)="myf('pane-1')">
 // codes
</div>
```

> [**Working Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-y9hnth)